# What date format is this date "2021-08-03T04:10:07.502-0700"?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I encountered a date format with timezone as `GMT` but I don't understand what is the hyphen part after microseconds in the above date and what will be its format to parse both ways?

So for this date (without hyphen): `"2021-08-03T04:10:07.502"`, the format is `YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS`

**Q1:** And for this date (with hyphen): `"2021-08-03T04:10:07.502-0700"`, the format is: ??

**Q2:** Is the hyphen part the timezone `GMT`?

<strike>**Q3:** If the date is in with the hyphen form after microseconds, how can one add X number of digits to address it?</strike>

Prospective Java code:

```
String dateFormatWithHyphen = "?"; // replace ? with that format
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatWithHyphen);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
return dateFormat;
```

Comment: it's [ISO 8601 international date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: @phuclv Thanks for your quick reply. So 0700 = GMT - 7 ?

Comment: It is probably it is UTC - 7.   But in theory, you don't know what an "unknown" date format actually represents unless someone / something tells you.  (Who knows what weird funkiness the code that generated the date might do?  Who knows if (say) their clock was out of sync by (say) 30 minutes?)

Comment: @StephenC So I know its GMT for sure (as someone has told me explicitly).

Comment: Well ... they are explicitly incorrect.  Timezones are NOT defined relative to GMT.  They are defined relative to UTC.  Please read the link provided by phuclv above.

Comment: The difference between GMT and UTC is irrelevant in common business-oriented situations. Not worth quibbling over unless you are doing rocket science or GPS/Galileo satellite calculations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

Diagram of your input string, containing a date, a separator, a time-of-day, and an offset-from-UTC.

```
2021-08-03T04:10:07.502-0700
  ^date^  ^   ^time^   ^offset
       separator
```

Parse your date with time-of-day and offset-from-UTC as an `java.time.OffsetDateTime` object.

```java
OffsetDateTime
.parse( 
    "2021-08-03T04:10:07.502-0700" , 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseLenient()
    .append( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )
    .appendPattern( "xx" )
    .toFormatter()
)
.toString()
```

> 2021-08-03T04:10:07.502-07:00

## Q1: And for this date (with hyphen): "2021-08-03T04:10:07.502-0700", the format is: ??

That string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

However, that string omits the optional COLON character between the hours and minutes of the offset-from-UTC. I would suggest always including that COLON for maximum compatibility in machines. And the COLON makes it more readable too for humans. So use this:

> 2021-08-03T04:10:07.502-07:00

## Q2: Is the hyphen part the timezone GMT?

The HYPHEN-MINUS character in front of `0700` means the offset of seven hours is *behind* the temporal prime meridian of UTC.

- `-07:00` means seven hours behind UTC, as seen in the Americas.

- `+07:00` means seven hours ahead of UTC, as seen in Asia such as Thailand, Vietnam, Indonesia.

UTC is the new GMT, practically speaking, with regard to common business-oriented situations. If you are doing rocket science or GPS/Galileo satellite calculations, you should research the difference. If you are programming for purchase orders and invoices, don't worry about it.

Regarding your phrase, “the timezone GMT”… that is a contradiction. UTC/GMT is *not* a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). It is the baseline against which offsets are defined: a certain number of hours-minutes-seconds. What longitude is to the [prime meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian), offsets are to UTC. Time zones are much more. [Time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) are a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by politicians.

## Q3: If the date is in with the hyphen form after microseconds, how can one add X number of digits to address it?

Actually, the `.502` is [*milliseconds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond), not [*microseconds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond).

And no, the date is up front, the `2021-08-03` part, August 3rd, 2021.

The `T` separates the date portion from the time portion. The third portion is the offset of `-07:00`.

## Code

You said:

> `DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatWithHyphen);`
> `dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in *java.time*. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such.

Use `OffsetDateTime` to represent a date with time-of-day as seen with a particular [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

If your input included the optional COLON, we could simply do this:

```java
String input = "2021-08-03T04:10:07.502-07:00" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Without the COLON, we must specify a formatting pattern. We can build up a `DateTimeFormatter` object by using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

```java
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseLenient()
    .append( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME )
    .appendPattern( "xx" )
    .toFormatter()
;
```

Use that formatter.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2021-08-03T04:10:07.502-07:00

Well, that code works. But the ideal solution would be convincing the publisher of your data to use the full ISO 8601 format including the COLON in every offset.